# Thermal conductivity of a liquid (I)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, non-equilibrium

> **Problem statement**: Thermal conductivity of a liquid increase with the density according to the expression: $$ \lambda = \dfrac{\lambda_0}{1-b(\rho-\rho_0)}$$ where $\lambda_0, b, \rho_0 >0$. Suppose also that this material can be considered as incompressible, in such a way that the equation of state is $\text{d}\rho = -\alpha \rho \text{d}T$ (pressure is decoupled from the density, $\kappa_T \sim 0$). A not too deep layer of that liquid is heated on its free surface ($z=0$), in such a way that: $$ \lambda \left(\dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}z}\right)_{z=0} = \phi_0 >0.$$ With these hypothesis, propose and solve the differential equations that give us the temperature and density as a function of depth $\rho(z), T(z)$. Check that at the bottom  ($z \rightarrow -\infty$), both density and temperature reach constant values. Determine the difference between the surface temperature and the bottom temperature. For simplicity, take $\rho(z=0)=\rho_0$.

**My solution:** Suppose we have a liquid with a thermal conductivity that is
$$ \lambda =\dfrac{\lambda_0}{1-b(\rho-\rho_0)}, \qquad \lambda_0, b, \rho_0 >0. \tag{a}$$
(I don't know what liquids verify this experimental equation, if anyone knows...)

I do some approximations:

- It's incompressible, so the state equation is
  $$\text{d}\rho = -\alpha \rho \text{d}T \tag{b}$$
  and of course, $\kappa_T \sim 0$. A not too deep layer of this liquid is heated on its free surface ($z=0$) so
  $$ \lambda \left( \dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}z}\right)_{z=0} = \phi_0 >0. \tag{c}$$

Let be $$ A \equiv -\dfrac{\alpha b \phi_0}{\lambda_0} <0, \quad B\equiv \dfrac{1+b\rho_0}{b} >0, \quad C\equiv \dfrac{\rho_0 +B}{\rho_0} >0, \quad D \equiv AB <0.$$

I know that (from entropy balance):
$$ \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z} \left(\lambda \dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}z}\right)=0 \tag{1}$$
so
$$ \lambda \dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}z} = C, \quad \forall z \in (-\infty,0]. \tag{2}$$
From (c) and (2) we have
$$ \lambda \dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}z} = \phi_0 >0, \qquad \forall z \in (-\infty,0].\tag{3}$$
Using the chain rule  in (3) and (b), we write
$$ \dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}z} =\dfrac{\phi_0}{\lambda} =\dfrac{\text{d}T}{\text{d}\rho} \dfrac{\text{d}\rho}{\text{d}z} = -\dfrac{1}{\alpha \rho}\dfrac{\text{d}\rho}{\text{d}z}$$
so
$$ \boxed{\rho'(z) = -\dfrac{\alpha \phi_0}{\lambda_0} \rho (z) \bigl( 1- b (\rho(z)-\rho_0)\bigr)}.\tag{4}$$
The solution of Eqn. (4) is
$$ \boxed{\rho(z) = \dfrac{B}{C \text{e}^{-Dz}-1}}. \tag{5}$$
Substituting the equation (5) in (3)
$$ \dfrac{\text{d}T(z)}{\text{d}z} =\dfrac{\phi_0}{\lambda \bigl( \rho(z)\bigr)}$$
so
$$ \boxed{-\dfrac{\alpha}{D}\text{d}T = \left( \dfrac{C \text{e}^{-Dz}-2}{C\text{e}^{-Dz}-1}\right) \text{d}z}, \tag{6}$$ 
and integrating this, we have
$$\boxed{T(z) = E-\dfrac{1}{\alpha} \left[ Dz +\log |\text{e}^{Dz}-C|\right]}. \tag{7} $$

- Density at the free surface:
  $$ \rho (0) = \rho_0$$
  but at the bottom
  $$ \underset{z \longrightarrow -\infty}{\lim} \rho(z) = 0. \tag{8}$$

> The solution of (8) at the bottom is zero and it's not physically acceptable, **where's my mistake**? $$ \underset{z\longrightarrow -\infty}{\lim} T(z) = \infty$$ and diverges. What's wrong?

From **Non-Equilibrium Thermodynamics Theory** (for example *Jan Sengers, 2006*):

- **Mass balance**: $$ \partial_t \rho=-\nabla (\rho \textbf{v})$$
  and since the liquid is motionless $\textbf{v}\equiv 0$, so the deviatoric stress tensor is $\Pi \equiv 0$ and
  $$ \partial_t \rho = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \rho=\rho(z).$$
- **Momentum balance**: $$\partial_t (\rho \textbf{v})= -\nabla (\rho \textbf{v} \textbf{v}-\Pi)= +\textbf{f}_v-\nabla P.$$ There is hydrostatic equilibrium, then $\textbf{f}_v -\nabla P =0$. Equation (1) is from here.
- **Entropy balance**: $$ \partial_t (\rho s)= -\nabla \bigl(\rho s \textbf{v} +\dfrac{1}{T} (\textbf{Q}-\sum \mu_k \textbf{J}_k)\bigr) + \dot{S} $$
  where the production of entropy is
  $$\dot{S} =\textbf{Q} \cdot \nabla (1/T) +\dfrac{1}{T} \Phi : (\nabla \textbf{v})^{(s)} -\sum \textbf{J}_k \cdot \nabla (\mu_k /T) -\dfrac{1}{T}\sum \mu_k \xi_k$$. The equation (2) comes from here.
- *Fenomenological relation*: Fourier's law
  $$\textbf{Q} = -\lambda \nabla T,  $$
  where $\lambda>0$ is the thermal conductivity.

Comment: Where did you get Eqn. 1 from?  Why do you think it is necessary for this equation to apply to this situation?

Comment: @ChesterMiller, I add more information about.

Comment: For hydrostatic equilibrium of an incompressible fluid (which is allowed to expand thermally only), $\frac{d\rho}{dz}=-\rho \alpha T(z)$, so $\rho=\rho_0\exp{(-\alpha\int_0^z{T(z')dz'})}$

Comment: Where did you get it?

Comment: The first equation I wrote was your 2nd equation in your post.  The 2nd equation I wrote is the analytic solution to that equation.

Comment: I have corrected some mistakes.

Comment: I have not idea where you got Eqn. 1 from.

Comment: @ChesterMiller, I 've changed the calculus for better understanding. My problem is the limit at the bottom.

Comment: So heat is being conducted from great depth to the surface with a constant flux?

Comment: It's weird, but I think that the calculus from the boundary condition (c) is right. The problem says not too deep layer and at the end, it asks you to take the limit at minus infinity, so this has no sense at all.

Comment: Please edit it the exact word-for-word statement of the problem.

Comment: Ok @ChesterMiller, I do.

Comment: Please check Eqn. 5.

Comment: Thank you @ChesterMiller, this are the mistake, the Egn. 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chester Miller (@ChesterMiller) found the mistake: the Egn. (5).

The equation (5) is
$$ \boxed{\rho(z)= \dfrac{B}{(C-2)\text{e}^{-Dz}+1} = \rho_0 \dfrac{1+b\rho_0}{\text{e}^{\frac{\alpha \phi_0}{\lambda_0} (1+b\rho_0)z}+b\rho_0}}, \tag{*}$$
so, now the limits are right
$$ \rho(0)= \rho_0 >0$$
and 
$$\underset{z\rightarrow -\infty}{\lim} \rho(z)=\rho_0 +\dfrac{1}{b}\equiv \rho_F >0.$$
Substituting the equation (*) in (b) we obtain
$$ \int_{\rho_0}^\rho \text{d}(\log \rho) =-\alpha \int_{T_0}^T \text{d}T$$
and we have
$$ \boxed{T(z) = T_0 +\dfrac{1}{\alpha} \log \left( \dfrac{\text{e}^{-Dz}+ b\rho_0}{1+ b\rho_0}\right)= T_0 +\dfrac{1}{\alpha} \log \left[ \dfrac{\text{e}^{\frac{\alpha \phi_0}{\lambda_0} (1+b\rho_0)z}+ b\rho_0}{1+b\rho_0 }\right]}.$$
These limits also fit very well 
$$ T(0)= T_0 >0$$
and
$$ \underset{z \rightarrow -\infty}{\lim}T(z) = T_0 +\dfrac{1}{\alpha} \log \left(\dfrac{b\rho_0}{1+b\rho_0}\right) = T_0 +\Delta T\equiv T_F, \quad 0 < T_F < T_0,$$
so $\Delta T <0.$

Comment: It seems to me your equation says $T_F<T_0$, which is correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad.